# C# Wpf simple listviewitem event binding won't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I ve a very simple listview which itemsource is bound to a collection. Then I ve a delegatecommand (from Prism) which I want to call when I click on one of the items. Unfortunatly the binding in the itemsource wont work. When I set the attachedcommandbehavior directly in the listview it call the method.

Maybe someone can help.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding col}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="c:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="PreviewMouseDown"/>
                <Setter Property="c:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>

 public ObservableCollection<string> col { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command => _Command = _Command ?? new DelegateCommand<object>(e => cmd(e));
    private ICommand _Command;

    public void cmd (object e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
    }

    public ViewModelCustom()
    {
        col = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        col.Add("a");
        col.Add("b");
        col.Add("C");
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to create property inside ViewModel and track the changes in set method instead of command

```
public T SelectedItem
{
   get { return _selectedItem; }
   set 
   { 
       _selectedItem = value; 
       // User selected another element here, do what you want
   }
}
```